# Using if function in MATLAB Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have created the following block diagram on Matlab Simulink. It should give OUT1=1 OUT2=0 when INPUT>=0 and  OUT1=0 OUT2=1 when INPUT<0. But it does not give the expected results. What is the reason for that. Any advice to make it work correctly would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your blocks are not connected. Check the connections. (you see, that it is not a solid line.

Comment: No they are connected. In matlab simulink connection between If block and if action subsystem is indicated by a dashed line.

Comment: If a constant value block connected to u1 input it gives expected results, when constant changed to positive or negative. But it don't work when signal builder block connected to input u1.

Comment: ah alright, didn't remembered that.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you are seeing can be explained by noting the following:

- The output from the If Subsystem acts like an enable signal.
- By default, the Output Ports of an If Action Subsystem are set to *hold* their values when the (sub)system is disabled.

This can be changed by going to the parameters dialog of the Output Port (within the If Action Subsystems) and changing the ***Output when disabled*** property to *reset*.  You'll also want to change the default value to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases an IF is translated to a [switch](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/switch.html). You calculate cases and select the one which is intended. Here you could connect a constant [1 0] and a constant [0 1] to the first and third input and the sign block from your solution to the second input.

Answer (score 0):

This if function block thing didn't work. So I come up with a different approach to get the result I wanted using the sign block. Solution is posted below. Thank you for everyone for trying to help.

[image]